# Are the currents on this planet realistic?

Tags: planets, climate

The planet rotates east to west, which is the opposite of earth. Its days are about 27 hours.

[image]

Comment: Downvotes without comment are unhelpful, folks.

Comment: "East to west" rotation is a bit problematic.  See the Wikipedia article on [Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus).  There are basically two definitions.  One is that the stars always rise in the east (and usually the Sun also, unless the day is over a year long).  The other is that north is defined in terms of the whole system, and then the planet can be retrograde like yours.  But if this is the main planet in the system, why reverse the definition of north according to the star's rotation?

Comment: @MikeSerfas It’s not a problem at all. The universe doesn’t have an “up” or “down,” so if the bottom of this drawing is the North pole, it is identical to earth. Our association between “North” ans “Up” is not rational. Also, OP didn’t say it was a retrograde orbit, so we must assume it rotates opposite our own in a normal orbit.

Comment: This is in the format of a normal map, north is the top south is the bottom, most of the landmass is in the south

Comment: @VogonPoet - Flipping the map this way restores the sun rising in the east.  However, if the planet revolves (not orbits) in the opposite direction from its star or some other important planet, you might say it is "retrograde rotation" with a north pole as originally illustrated.  (That doesn't change your point that flipping the map makes the currents easier to compare to Earth, even if then we label the Sun as rising in the "west" and have "south" at the top of the map.

Comment: We know you didn't mention it but it changes everything if your rotation is retrograde to your orbit. Also I understand you "did not flip the map" perfectly. But if you *did* flip the map then the planet would work exactly like Earth. You chose to put North on top, and the planet doesn't care about the map. The wind will flow from "x" to "y". Calling it "east" or "west" is meaningless and arbitrary. Your physical planet is no different from Earth unless it orbits in retrograde. That is the answer to your question.

Comment: @VogonPoet I understand your logic now

Comment: I have not decided the orbit yet

Answer (score 3):

> Are the currents on this planet realistic?

Not as depicted, but I can't say if it's for the drawing skill or for the underlying concept.

As a general remark, currents should form closed loops. This is constantly violated in your map.

More in particular remarks:

[image]

1. here the southern current starts out of nowhere. If you take water out of a place without replacing it, that place will lose water
2. what causes the Coriolis force to switch here? the southernmost gyre is counterclockwise, the northernmost is clockwise, and they both seem to be south from the equator.
3. water currents are not photons, if they cross they also interfere with each other.
4. what causes the easternmost gyre to suddenly point north?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I am by no means an expert on currents. But I took the liberty to draw something that might be a bit more realistic.

I have ignored continental shelves as I can't see any that's clearly defined, you might want to look into that.

The blue currents are cold, the red warm and the black are neutral.

I suggest checking out the videos of Artifexian. This is the one I used to learn what little I know about currents:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_E9UShtyY8

[image: Currents]

Comment: that's very similar to how I redid it

Comment: @Kijivu the major difference is the shallow counter current at the equator. which we do see on earth